# Linking combo box (JQuery preferrably)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, drop-down-menu

I am wondering if anyone has any experience using a JQuery plugin that converts a html

```
<select> 
  <option> Blah </option> 
</select>
```

combo box into something (probably a div) where selecting an item acts the same as clicking a link.

I guess you could probably use javascript to handle a selection event (my javascript knowledge is a little in disrepair at the moment) and 'switch' on the value of the combo box but this seems like more of a hack.

Your advice, experience and recommendations are appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The simple solution is to use

```
$("#mySelect").change(function() {
  document.location = this.value;
});
```

This creates an onchange event on the select box that redirects you to the url stored in the value field of the selected option.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure where you want to link to when you click the Div, but given something like this perhaps would work:

```
<select id="mySelect">
  <option value="1">Option 1</option>
  <option value="2">Option 2</options>
</select>
<div id="myDiv"/>
```

and the following JQuery creates a list of `<div>` elements, a goes to a URL based on the value of the option:

```
$("#mySelect option").each(function() {
    $("<div>" + $(this).text() + "</div>").appendTo($("#myDiv")).bind("click", $(this).val(), function(event) {
        location.href = "goto.php?id=" + event.data;
    });
});
$("#mySelect").remove();
```

Does this do what you want?

Answer (score 1):

If you're going to have a lot of select boxes that you want to allow to use as redirects, without having to define them independently, try something similar to:

```
$("[id*='COMMON_NAME']").change(function() {
    document.location = this.value;
});
```

And have your select boxes be named accordingly:

```
<select id="COMMON_NAME_001">...</select>
<select id="COMMON_NAME_002">...</select>
```

This creates a onchange event for all IDs containing "COMMON_NAME" to do a redirect of the `<option>` value.

Answer (score 0):

This bit of javascript in the 'select':

```
onchange="if(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value!=''){this.form.submit()}"
```

It's not ideal (because form submissions in ASP.NET MVC which I'm using don't appear to use the routing engine for URLs) but it does its job.